# C# bool variable does not get assigned

Tags: c#, properties, variable-assignment

I have been trying to diagnose a bug for the last few days with no real success. It looks as if variables are not being assigned correctly. I have a property that is suppose to return true if a transportation request is cancelled, and while the check evaluates to true, the property still returns false. I tried to use a local variable in the method I was referencing that property to see if that behaves differently, but same issue occurs.

```
internal bool SendFromCancelled
    => SendFromRemoteWorkcellRequest is { Status: TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled };
....

// In Some method

...
var sendToCancelled = SendToRemoteWorkcellRequest is { Status: TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled };

TransportationRequestStatus sendToStatus = TransportationRequestStatus.Started;
if (SendToRemoteWorkcellRequest != null)
{
    sendToStatus = SendToRemoteWorkcellRequest.Status;
    sendToCancelled = SendToRemoteWorkcellRequest?.Status == TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled;
    sendToCancelled = SendToRemoteWorkcellRequest.Status == TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled;
    sendToCancelled = sendToStatus == TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled;
    if (sendToStatus == TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled)
    {
        sendToCancelled = true;
    }
}

// Added both the local variable and property for testing purpose; both are false by this point
// regardless if sendToStatus is TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled.
if (SendToCancelled || sendToCancelled || SendFromCancelled || OrderCancelled)
{
    return RemoteOrderStatus.Canceled;
}
```

TransportationRequestStatus is an enum defined in another project.
SendToRemoteWorkcellRequest is of type TransportationRequest, with the Status property defined as

```
public TransportationRequestStatus Status { get; set; }
```

When debugging with breakpoints in VS, All sendToCancelled assignments have the rhs evaluate to true, yet sendToCancelled remains false. Even when

```
if (sendToStatus == TransportationRequestStatus.Canceled)
```

evaluates to true, the branch isn't taken.

I added various statements that attempt to do the same thing but each fails.
I also created some rather extensive unit tests for the properties in question and they all pass as expected. This is only occurs during normal runtime.

This issues is really confusing, and I have no idea where to even begin diagnosing and resolving it. Is there a technical detail I overlooked.

Comment: What does the type of `SendFromRemoteWorkcellRequest` look like? What happens if you put a breakpoint on your `SendFromCancelled` property?

Comment: `public TransportationRequest SendToRemoteWorkcellRequest { get; set; }`, The `TransportationRequest` class just has many properties of the form `public PropertyType PropertyName { get; set; }`, no fields or methods.